# how to send 10000 http request for every 20 seconds using JMETER

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

What should be the ramp up time when i need to send 10k request[each request has 6http subsequent calls], I need to send 1 request per minute. and i need to send one request for every 20seconds

Answer (score 0):

Your post contains 4 questions which are mutually exclusive so I provide a generic answer:

1. If you want to send X requests at exactly the same moment:

   - Add X thread (virtual users) to [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
   - Add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to the request and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to X
2. If you want to send 1 request per minute - add [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) to your request and set `Target Throughput` to `1`
3. If you want to send 1 request each 20 seconds - the same approach as for point 2 but `Target Throughput` will be `3`

Ramp-up is the time period for starting virtual users, normally normal people use it for gradual load increase, for example if you have 10 users and 10 seconds ramp-up JMeter will start 1 user each second, if you have 10 users and 20 seconds ramp-up JMeter will start each user each 2 seconds, etc.